# How to use if statements in a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, if-statement

My if statement did not work and was wondering if I could please get some help. I would type in "FnPrint" and my if statement would not work.

```
puts "hi"
g = gets()
# Class for print command
x = "FnPrint"
class Fnprint
  def Print
    if x = g
      puts "it worked"
    else
      puts "no"
    end
  end
end

Fnprint.new.Print
```

I kept getting this when I tried to run it:

```
lang.rb:9:in `Print': undefined local variable or method `g' for #<Fnprint:0x007f9379939040> (NameError)
from lang.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Make sure you use == when testing for equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing many incorrect stuffs here

1) Incorrect comparison operator `=`  instead of `==`

2) Trying to access a vaiables `g` and `x` which are outside the scope of the class.

3) Your method name is a constant (In Ruby anything that starts with a capital letter is constant). The method name should be all downcase and seperated with `_` in case of mutiword.

```
class FnPrint
  def print(x)
    g = gets.strip
    if x == g
      puts 'it worked'
    else
      puts 'no'
    end
  end
end

fn_print_object = FnPrint.new
fn_print_object.print('FnPrint')
```

Comment: take `x` as method argument and pass it while caling that method and put `g = gets()` inside method call

Comment: How would i do that? Could you please show some example code? I am new to Ruby. I am trying to learn it. Sorry if I am causing any hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following:

```
if x == g
```

when you do

```
if x = g
```

you simply tell ruby to assign the value of `g` to `x`.

You are also trying to access variables out of the `Print` method scope. Please consider refactoring your code as follow:

```
class FnPrint
  def print(x)
    if x == gets().strip
      puts "it worked"
    else
      puts "no"
    end
  end
end

puts "hi"
FnPrint.new.print('FnPrint')
```

Couple points to understand:

1. [String#strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip) remove leading and trailing whitespace.
2. method name should be lowercase
3. Class name should be camelcased (`FnPrint`, `FooBar`, `Foo`, ...)
4. `print` is an instance method of class `FnPrint`
5. `FnPrint.new` create a new instance of class `FnPrint` so you can call `print` on it

Answer (score 0):

```
if x = g #=> is Assignment
if x == g #=> is Comparison
```

Answer (score 0):

`if x=g` [**assigns**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html) `g` to `x` and then assesses whether this is truthy.

`if x == g` assesses whether `x` and `g` are [**equal**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-3D-3D).

You probably meant to write something like this:

```
puts 'hi'
#
class Fnprint
  def print
    x = 'FnPrint'
    g = gets.strip
    if x == g
      puts 'it worked'
    else
      puts 'no'
    end
  end
end

Fnprint.new.print
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if x=g
```

Is actually an assignment and will return  the value of g to the if statement.

Use the comparison operator `==`